# HybridAuth Facebook login error: "Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, read_friendlists"

Tags: facebook, hybridauth

I am using the `HybridAuth` library with CodeIgniter `Bonfire` for adding login functionality with Facebook . I added the library and all related required files into `Bonfire`.

After clicking on the *Login with Facebook* button, I am redirected to the  Facebook authorization page, but Facebook gives this error:

> Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, read_friendlists. This
>   message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore
>   these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid
>   permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions..

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on **@luschn**'s answer, the [permissions which `HybridAuth` requests from Facebook by default](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html) (as of version 2.4.1) are `email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website, offline_access, read_stream, publish_stream, read_friendlists`.

Here's how to remove those depreciated scopes in your `HybridAuth` config file:

```php
<?php
return
    array(
        'base_url' => 'http://localhost/your/hybridauth/endpoint/index.php',

        'providers' => array (

            'Facebook' => array (
                'enabled' => true,
                'keys'    => array ( 'id' => 'YOUR-APP-ID', 'secret' => 'YOUR-APP-SECRET-TOKEN' ),
                'scope'   => 'email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website, read_stream',
                'trustForwarded' => false
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

All those scopes/permissions are deprecated since years - which is exactly what the error message tells you, they just don´t exist. You need to check out the Facebook docs to find out which permissions exactly you need. The [API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/) is a good place to find out.

Answer (score 2):

current answer of @Arman H would not work, IF YOU DEFINE `email` in `scope` you will receive public profile and email adress

```
<?php
return
    array(
        'base_url' => 'http://localhost/your/hybridauth/endpoint/index.php',
        'providers' => array (
            'Facebook' => array (
                'enabled' => true,
                'keys'    => array ( 'id' => 'YOUR-APP-ID', 'secret' => 'YOUR-APP-SECRET-TOKEN' ),
                'scope'   => 'email',
                'trustForwarded' => false
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: I believe you receive the public profile no matter what you request. Were you trying to NOT get the public profile?

Answer (score 2):

simply goto app advance settings and upgrade your app version, it should be at least 2.7

[image]

Comment: mine is at version 2.11 but still I am getting that error

Comment: Its mean you have issue in your callback url,  encode your url properly. @aidonsnous